# change image on CustomTableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am creating an application where I am using custom `TableviewCell` which contains checkboxes, so I put an `imageview` as unchecked image on that if the user select a row then I want to change the image as checked so how can I change this image on `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

I tried this but it wont work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *checkBoxIdentifier = @"checkBox";
    UITableViewCell *cell ;
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBox" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    cell.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedimage"];
}
```

Comment: Your 'cell' variable is not an instance of UITableViewCell as is declared. Try changing it to your own subclass of UITableViewCell (I think its CheckBox).

Answer (score 4):

Just Simply do this, nothing else required:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //replace 'CustomCell' with your custom cell class name
    CustomCell *cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedimage"];
}
```

**EDIT:**
However if your tableview gets reloaded, you won't find the cell as selected. for that purpose in your custom cell class header file create a BOOL property:

```
@property (retain) BOOL isSelected;
```

change your didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //replace 'CustomCell' with your custom cell class name
    CustomCell *cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.checkBoxImageView.isSelected = YES;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

for deselecting already checked row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //replace 'CustomCell' with your custom cell class name
    CustomCell *cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.checkBoxImageView.isSelected = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     /*
      initialize and set cell properties like you are already doing
     */
     if(cell.isSelected) {
          cell.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedimage"];
     }
     else {
          cell.checkBoxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedimage"];
     }
}
```